# get() in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to fetch values for keys 'product' and 'orderNumber'
When I do so using statement `product, order = mydict.get("product"), mydict.get("orderNumber")`
it works, However if I try this in a loop to get more data - it throws an error.

Please advise Thanks

```
mylist = [{'dependency': {'dependencyType': 'Rides On', 'orderActionType': 'PR', 'orderNumber': '123456789', 'product': 'random'}, 'latestOrderVersion': '1', 'mainComponentServiceType': 'random', 'orderActionType': 'PR', 'orderNumber': '987654321', 'parentRelation': 'NA', 'product': 'random Access'}]
mydict  = {}
for line in mylist:
    mydict.update(line)

print(mydict)
print(type(mydict))

product, order = mydict.get("product"), mydict.get("orderNumber")
print(product,order)

for key in mydict:
    product = key.get("product")
    if not product:
        continue
    print(product)
```

Output:

```
{'dependency': {'dependencyType': 'Rides On', 'orderActionType': 'PR', 'orderNumber': '123456789', 'product': 'random'}, 'latestOrderVersion': '1', 'mainComponentServiceType': 'random', 'orderActionType': 'PR', 'orderNumber': '987654321', 'parentRelation': 'NA', 'product': 'random Access'}
<class 'dict'>
random Access 987654321
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mike/handle_rt_iwant_v5.py", line 15, in <module>
    product = key.get("product")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: As it is said in the error, `mydict`is a dictionnary which has .get() as method returning the value for the given key. In your for loop, key is each key of your dictionnary and a key is a string, it does't have any key/value associated

Comment: `key.get("product")` -> `mydict[key].get("product")`. Or just loop over `mydict.values()` instead

Comment: It's important to read error messages and do your own debugging *before* asking

Comment: Thanks @Clément that was helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
                product_dict = my_list[0]
                result = {}
                for key, value in product_dict.items():
                    if isinstance(value, list):
                        for item in value:
                            if isinstance(item, dict):
                                for key, value in item.items():
                                    if keys == 'orderNumber':
                                        result.update({keys: values})
                                    elif values == 'MIS':
                                        values = result.get("orderNumber")
                                        result.update({'MIS': values})
                                    else:
                                        continue
                            else:
                                continue
                    else:
                        if key == 'orderNumber':
                            result.update({key: value})
                        elif value == 'MIS':
                            value = result.get("orderNumber")
                            result.update({'MIS': value})
                        else:
                            continue
```

Thanks everyone,
I was able to correct my usage of get() and fetch values for keys 'product' and 'orderNumber' using the above piece of code.
Thanks for the lead, Appreciate it!

RESULT:

```
result = result.get('MIS')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already been said, that you are trying to use a dict method on a string. I am not sure what you want as a output but do you may look for something like this?

```
mylist = [
    {
        'dependency':
         {
             'dependencyType': 'Rides On',
             'orderActionType': 'PR',
             'orderNumber': '123456789',
             'product': 'MIS'
         },
        'latestOrderVersion': '1',
        'mainComponentServiceType': 'MISM',
        'orderActionType': 'PR',
        'orderNumber': '987654321',
        'parentRelation': 'NA',
        'product': 'MIS Access'
    }
]

if mylist[0].get("product", False):
    print(mylist[0]["product"])
if mylist[0].get("orderNumber", False):
    print(mylist[0]["orderNumber"])

for value in mylist[0].values():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        if value.get("product", False):
            print(value['product'])
        if value.get("orderNumber", False):
            print(value['orderNumber'])
```

Answer (score 0):

please use dictionary.item() for iterating in loops for dictionary in python 3 version

```
  mylist = [{'dependency': {'dependencyType': 'Rides On', 'orderActionType': 'PR', 'orderNumber': '123456789', 'product': 'MIS'}, 'latestOrderVersion': '1', 'mainComponentServiceType': 'MISM', 'orderActionType': 'PR', 'orderNumber': '987654321', 'parentRelation': 'NA', 'product': 'MIS Access'}]
    mydict  = {}
    for line in mylist:
        mydict.update(line)
    
    print(mydict)
    print(type(mydict))
    
    product, order = mydict.get("product"), mydict.get("orderNumber")
    print(product,order)
    


    for key in mydict.items():
        ke = key[0]
        val = key[1]
        if "product" in ke:
            print(ke)
            print(val)
```

## Another method

```
  for key, value in mydict.items():  
        if key == "product":
            print(value)
```